# Compare Numpy and Matlab code that uses random permutation

Tags: python, matlab, random, numpy, permutation

I'm having problems to compare the output of two code because of random number state.

I'm comparing the MATLAB `randperm` function with the output of the equivalent `numpy.random.permutation` function but, even if I've set the seed to the same value with a MATLAB `rand('twister',0)` and a python `numpy.random.seed(0)` I'm obtaining different permutations.

I've to say that the result of MATLAB's `rand` and numpy `numpy.random.rand` are the same if the seed are set like above.

Comment: They may be using different random number generation algorithms. In that case, even if the seed is the same, the output will be different.

Comment: If you just need to compare to codes, you can output a sufficient number of your random permutations using either Matlab or Python and save them to a file. Then the other version can just read in the values from file. This may be the simplest workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. While the random number generator is identical, the function which converts your random number stream into a random permutation is different. There is no specified standard algorithm which describes the expected result.

To solve this issue, you have to use the same library in both tools.

Comment: Some suggestion how to do that?

Comment: There are many possibilities. I don't know what you are planning to do, thus I can't give a recommendation. Some ideas that come to my mind: 1) Generate a dll from your relevant matlab functions, call it from python 2) Create a standalone exe from the m-functions, call it from python 3) Call the m-functions via com or similar automation 4) Call the python code in matlab using system shell 5) Use `org.python.util.PythonInterpreter` in matlab to have access to python.

Comment: Just implement your own permutation algorithm in exactly the same way in python and matlab, for sure you can find some recipes on the web.